# How to bake custom view in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am very fascinated by cake's bake. Currently it bakes only CURD method if controller has associated Model.
e.g.

```
cake bake controller users
```

it will generate all CURD method(index,view, add, edit, delete). 
But i want to generate other method from baking like generate in ROR.
like,

```
cake bake controller users custom_func
```

Generate view for this custom_func

Also how to generate custom_func view.

```
cake bake view users custom_func
```

Is it possible to generate custom method and view using bake? Is there any Plugin to help it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can bake:

```
cake bake view users custom_func
```

For that you need to create a template in the following directory:

```
YOUR_PROJECT\lib\Cake\Console\Templates\default\views

"create a custom_func.ctp file"
```

and also create a function in (core controller file):

```
YOUR_PROJECT\lib\Cake\Console\Templates\default\actions

"add a new function custom_func"
```

Or if you don't want that function to be universal, directly write into the users controller.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you can use some function, but You can prepare own templates in `app/Console/Templates`

Comment: That's not what i am asking does cake bake is able to generate view file based on the custom function like ROR.

Comment: Bake can only generates views for templates that exist, and only bakes controllers as a whole - you can't bake one action.